# convert to codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having a problem converting this to CI, I'm not familiar with sessions in CI, help me please

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["gids"])) {
    $_SESSION["gids"] = array();
}

//check for current product in visitor's shopping cart content
$i=0;
while ($i<count($_SESSION["gids"]) && $_SESSION["gids"][$i] != $_GET["add2cart"]) $i++;

if ($i < count($_SESSION["gids"])) //increase current product's item quantity
{

}
else //no such product in the cart - add it
{
    $_SESSION["gids"][] = $_GET["add2cart"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For setting a session variable, use:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('gids')
```

For getting data from a session variable:

```
$this->session->userdata('gids'); // returns falls if gids does not exists
```

For getting data from GET variable:

```
$this->input->get('add2cart');
```

Reference:
[CodeIgniter Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) 
[CodeIgniter Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you must be aware that by default CodeIgniter stores its session variables in the cookie. If you want the session to be stored somewhere that could hold large size data, change the settings so it uses database table to store session data. Open up system/application/config.php and change the $config['sess_use_database'] line in Session Variables section into :

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

and also create the session database table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

To use sessions, you must first load the session library : (for example, in system/application/controller/cmilestone.php)

```
function CMilestone(){
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->library('Session');
}
```

Then you could set the session from inside one of the method :

```
function something() {
   if ($this->session->userdata('gids') === false)  $this->session->set_userdata('gids',array());
   $i=0;
   $gids = $this->session->userdata('gids');
   while ($i<count($gids) && $gids[$i] != $_GET["add2cart"]) $i++;

 if ($i < count($gids)) //increase current product's item quantity
 {

 }
 else //no such product in the cart - add it
 {
     $gids[] = $_GET["add2cart"];
     $this->session->set_userdata('gids',$gids);
 }
```

But I think you should really use POST to do operations. If you want to use POST and CI's xss filter then the $_GET["add2cart"] would be replaced with $this->input->post('add2cart',true)